# scala regex for strings with double quotes

Tags: regex, scala, replace

I am struggling to concatenate a message with two texts into a single text using regex in scala

```
original message = "part1 "+" part2"
original message = "part1 "   + " part2"
original message = "part 1 "+    " part2"

concatenated message = "part1 part2"
```

What I am using is this code below (to replace atleast the + sign with null)

```
val line:String = """"text1"+"text2"""" //My original String which is "text1"+"text2"
val temp_line:String = line.replaceAll("\\+","")
println(temp_line)
```

It works fine and results "text1""text2". Is there a way to get the output "text1 text2" using regex?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is really unclear.  Does the message actually have quotes and plus signs in it?  Is concatenated message what you want to produce, regardless of the spaces and stuff (and quotes) in the other?  Do you want it to work for exactly two, or should it do something sensible with one or three?  Do you need to match exactly the word `part`, or are you illustrating that the text of the two must match, or could it be arbitrary text?

Comment: Yes. Original message has plus signs and quotes in it. Required result would be a single text enclosed in quotes which will contenatanation of all texts in the original message. I want the regex to also work for one or three. Part1 and part2 are sample texts which can be any arbitrary texts. Thanks for looking at this

Comment: Your question confuses me because none of this has anything to do with regex...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I am trying to do here is I am iterating over all lines in a file where lines can be "part1"+"part2" and I want to match "+" in that line and replace it with space so that line becomes "part1 part2" in that file using regex. The difficult part is there can be spaces between the double quotes and the plus sign like " +" or "+ ". I would like to know if there is a better way to do that in scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really not an ideal problem for regexes, but okay:

```
val Part = """"([^"]*)"(.*$)""".r    // Quotes, non quotes, quotes, then the rest
val Plus = """\s*\+\s*(.*)""".r      // Plus with optional spaces, then the rest

def parts(s: String, found: List[String] = Nil): String = s match {
  case Part(p,rest) => rest match {
    case "" => (p :: found).map(_.filter(c => !c.isWhitespace)).reverse.mkString(" ")
    case Plus(more) => parts(more, p :: found)
    case x => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"$p :$x:")
  }
  case x => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"|$x|")
}
```

This just takes the input string apart piece by piece; you can add printlns if you want to see how it works.  (Note that `+` is a special character in regex, so you need to escape it to match it.)

```
scala> parts(""""part1 "+" part2"""")
res1: String = part1 part2

scala> parts(""""part1 "   + " part2"""")
res2: String = part1 part2

scala> parts(""""part 1 "+    " part2"""")
res3: String = part1 part2
```

Comment: That worked though it's a bit complicated. I worked on a solution that uses split and replaceAll which is much easier to read and edit. Your solution is ideal to my problem though. Thanks.